# sphinx-apidoc vs autosummary

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I'm running into a bit of brick wall trying to work out the best way to implement automatic documentation generation for a Django project

my project structure is similar to the following:

```
myproj/           # project root
|- docs/          # docs root
|- myproj/        # package root
   |- app1/
   |- app2/
   |- app3/
   utils.py
   ...
```

I would like to automatically generate documentation for everything under the package root directory- and initially started using `sphinx-apidoc`, but then read something that implied I should be using autosummary instead and have not been able to find any information outlining what the difference between these two options is.

Comment: Information exists, what I am struggling with is working out which method I should be using, where, and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone else struggling to work it out, this is the guide I finally found that helped me clear up the confusion:

https://romanvm.pythonanywhere.com/post/autodocumenting-your-python-code-sphinx-part-ii-6/

In short, use autosummary

Comment: I see many recommendations to use autosummary, but I have still not found a way to make it document ALL my source tree. It seems I will have to keep using apidoc